# Jtree to JPanel

Tags: treeview, jpanel, draw, jtree, treemodel

I have a `JTree` object which uses `DefaultTreeModel` as model and I add/remove nodes respect to that model.

At that point, I need to show tree structure in graphical interface such as `JPanel`. How can I map `DefaultTreeModel` elements into `Jpanel` object? In other words, how can I draw `JTree` objects into `JPanel` object. Since tree can be modified, implementation should reflect the changes.

Thanks for your care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jtree);
p.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, sp);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but problem is little different. I want to show each elements of JTree as individual JPanel object and draw them in tree structure like binary tree.

Comment: So each on its own JPanel or all in one JPanel?